# How to loop a calculator/sending output to a file?

Tags: java

I'm making a calculator for practice however, I've run into some issues that I can't seem to figure out whatsoever.

So I have a basic understanding as to how loops work however, I've gotten to a point where I can't even figure out how to get it to fit into my coding and loop the calculator. As in, I'd like for the user to try one of the options, and then receive a prompt to try another option.

My other issue is that I don't know how to send solely the answer to another file. I know how to send a basic text to another file but this just seems complicated.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculators {

    public static void menudisplayer() {

        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in); // Create a Scanner object
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) 
        System.out.println(
                "1 - Add" + "\n" + "2  - Subtract" + "\n" + "3 - Divide " + "\n" + "4 - Multiply" + "\n"
                    + "5 - Average" + "\n" + "6 - Maximum"); //printing men

        System.out.println("Please type in the operation that you would like to use");
        String operations = myObj.nextLine(); // Read user input
        System.out.println("You Entered: " + operations + "\n"); // Output user input  

        double value1, value2, answer;
        Scanner scanvalues = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter any two Double Values" + "\n");
        value1 = scanvalues.nextDouble();
        value2 = scanvalues.nextDouble();

        if (operations.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
            System.out.println(answer = value1 + value2);
            System.out.println("value1=" + value1 + "\nvalue2=" + value2 + "\nAnswer=" + answer);
        } else if (operations.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
            System.out.println(answer = value1 - value2);
            System.out.println("value1=" + value1 + "\nvalue2=" + value2 + "\nAnswer=" + answer);
        } else if (operations.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
            System.out.println(answer = value1 / value2);
            System.out.println("value1=" + value1 + "\nvalue2=" + value2 + "\nAnswer=" + answer);
        } else if (operations.equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {
            System.out.println(answer = value1 * value2);
            System.out.println("value1=" + value1 + "\nvalue2=" + value2 + "\nAnswer=" + answer);
        } else if (operations.equalsIgnoreCase("5")) {
            System.out.println((answer = (value1 + value2) / 2));
            System.out.println("value1=" + value1 + "\nvalue2=" + value2 + "\nAnswer=" + answer);
        } else if (operations.equalsIgnoreCase("6")) {
            System.out.println(answer = Math.max(value1, value2));
            System.out.println("value1=" + value1 + "\nvalue2=" + value2 + "\nAnswer=" + answer);
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        menudisplayer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your *for* loop only applies to the first *System.out* because you did not put any parenthesis, I think what you want if the loop to apply to the whole sequence.

You code is:

```
public static void menudisplayer() {

    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i=0; i<7; i++) 
        System.out.println("1 - Add" + "\n" + "2  - Subtract" + "\n" + "3 - Divide " + "\n" + "4 - Multiply" + "\n" + "5 - Average" + "\n" + "6 - Maximum"); //printing men

    System.out.println("Please type in the operation that you would like to use");
    String operations = myObj.nextLine(); // Read user input
    System.out.println("You Entered: " + operations + "\n"); // Output user input

   // all your ifs

}
```

it should be

```
public static void menudisplayer() {

    Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {  // <- parenthesis here

        System.out.println("1 - Add" + "\n" + "2  - Subtract" + "\n" + "3 - Divide " + "\n" + "4 - Multiply" + "\n" + "5 - Average" + "\n" + "6 - Maximum"); //printing men

        System.out.println("Please type in the operation that you would like to use");
        String operations = myObj.nextLine(); // Read user input
        System.out.println("You Entered: " + operations + "\n"); // Output user input

       // all your ifs

    } // <- parenthesis here

}
```

It will now loop 7 times and give your user 7 trials.

If you want to make it an unlimited number of tries, you might want to replace the *for* loop by a *while* loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculators {

    public static void menudisplayer() {

        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in); // Create a Scanner object

        while(true) { // loops indefinitely

            System.out.println("0 - Exit" + "\n" + "1 - Add" + "\n" + "2  - Subtract" + "\n" + "3 - Divide " + "\n" + "4 - Multiply" + "\n" + "5 - Average" + "\n" + "6 - Maximum"); //printing men
            System.out.println("Please type in the operation that you would like to use");
            String operations = myObj.nextLine(); // Read user input

            // Break out of the loop if user chose 0
            if (operations.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
                break;

            System.out.println("You Entered: " + operations); // Output user input

            double value1, value2, answer=0;
            Scanner scanvalues = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("Enter any two Double Values" + "\n");
            value1 = scanvalues.nextDouble();
            value2 = scanvalues.nextDouble();

            if (operations.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                answer = value1 + value2;
            } else if (operations.equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                answer = value1 - value2;
            } else if (operations.equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                answer = value1 / value2;
            } else if (operations.equalsIgnoreCase("4")) {
                answer = value1 * value2;
            } else if (operations.equalsIgnoreCase("5")) {
                answer = (value1 + value2) / 2;
            } else if (operations.equalsIgnoreCase("6")) {
                answer = Math.max(value1, value2);
            }

            System.out.println("value1=" + value1 + "\nvalue2=" + value2 + "\nAnswer=" + answer + "\n");

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        menudisplayer();
    }
}
```

Output: User selects "1 - Add" twice then exists

```
0 - Exit
1 - Add
2  - Subtract
3 - Divide 
4 - Multiply
5 - Average
6 - Maximum
Please type in the operation that you would like to use
1
You Entered: 1
Enter any two Double Values
3
4
value1=3.0
value2=4.0
Answer=7.0

0 - Exit
1 - Add
2  - Subtract
3 - Divide 
4 - Multiply
5 - Average
6 - Maximum
Please type in the operation that you would like to use
1
You Entered: 1
Enter any two Double Values
4
5
value1=4.0
value2=5.0
Answer=9.0

0 - Exit
1 - Add
2  - Subtract
3 - Divide 
4 - Multiply
5 - Average
6 - Maximum
Please type in the operation that you would like to use
0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: I've tried your suggestion yet it caused my menu to repeat itself multiple times. It doesn't even loop back either. I thought I may have interpreted what you said poorly so I tried to copy the edits you made to my code recently and got the same outcome.

Comment: @Auriph I copied the full code with the while loop. And an example of the output to show it works as expected